# Ubuntu-process is not started from jenkins

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, sh

I am trying to run the below script to restart servicemix process from jenkins on an ubuntu server.

```
#!/bin/sh
killservicemix() {
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "apache-servicemix" > /dev/null
then
process=$(echo $(ps -elf | grep -v grep | grep "apache-servicemix" | awk '{print $4}'))
echo "killing service mix"
kill -9 $process ;
sleep 2;
killservicemix
fi
}
#Method to stop servicemix
stopservicemix() {
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "apache-servicemix" > /dev/null
   then
    echo "Stop Service mix"
    /home/ubuntu/apache-servicemix-4.3.0/bin/stop
    sleep 10;
    killservicemix
fi
}
stopservicemix
sleep 15

#restarting Servicemix
nohup /home/ubuntu/apache-servicemix-4.3.0/bin/start >/dev/null 2>&1 &
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    ps -elf|grep servicemix
    echo 'ServiceMix start command executed'
else
    echo 'ServiceMix start command failed'
fi
echo 'started Servicemix';
```

When i run this script from terminal it works fine.But when i run this from jenkins it will kill the servicemix process but it will not start it again and displays "ServiceMix start command executed".

I even tried  using Build parameter "dontKillMe" but still no result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the to disable the process tree killer.

```
java -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -jar jenkins.war
```

I came across the same issue recently trying to start an application server through Jenkins. It worked fine starting from the console, but the process disappeared when running a script from Jenkins.

This is due to how Jenkins handles its own processes. By default they are killed when the job is done to prevent the system from getting cluttered. By disabling the ProcessTree option, Jenkins will leave scripts (and background processes like services) running. That is the difference between your console working and Jenkins not.

`nohup /home/ubuntu/apache-servicemix-4.3.0/bin/start >/dev/null 2>&1 &` starts servicemix, but as soon as the job is done, that process gets killed. This is why it looks as if the process wasn't started.

Comment: I tried using 
java -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -jar jenkins.war
But still its not working. I had read about ProcessTree hence had tried using Build parameter "dontKillMe".But didnt work for me.